# How to force MVC to scaffold string fields by @Html.DropDownListFor helper method instead of @Html.EditFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

This is my model

```
public class FacePart
{
    public long Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set}
    public string Area {get;set}
}
```

I just want to store three values in Area field. (Left, Right and L & R). By default MVC scaffolds string fields by @Html.Editfor helper method. so in this case I have to change it to @Html.DropDownListFor helper method manually.

As a lazy programmer I just want to know Is there anyway to force MVC to scaffold some string fields by @Html.DropDownListFor helper method instead of @Html.EditFor.

Comment: You want the user to have the option to choose from 3 constant options ?

Comment: @Ofiris: yes. But actually I want to change the default scaffolding behavior for string fields.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use [`UIHint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.uihintattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and "nudge" MVC to use a view of your choosing (though now it's still an editor template, but it's *your* editor template).

The other option is to change the scaffolding at the root level:

```
* SomeSolution
    * SomeMVCProject
        * Properties
        * [CodeTemplates]
            * [AddView]
                * [CSHTML]
                    * Create.tt
                    * Delete.tt
                    * Details.tt
                    * Edit.tt
                    * Empty.tt
                    * List.tt
```

Which is essentially copying the CodeTemplates folder over from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Web\MVC 4\` and placing it in your project, remove the "Custom Tool" property from the files, then modify as you see fit. You can also add your own in there which will show up when you go to "Add View".

Comment: :@Brad: I tried this [UIHint("DropDownList")] but it didn't work?